# Any() not working when querying a SharePoint list

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, linq, sharepoint

I'm trying to query a Sharepoint list to find whether the username exists in the list or not. I'm using LINQ in this. Code which I tried:

```
SPList l = web.Lists["Acknowledgements"];
var listEnumeration = l.Items.OfType<SPListItem>();
bool a = listEnumeration.Any(p => p["User"].ToString().Equals(@"SHAREPOINT\system"));
```

But the bool is returning false even though after debugging this, the XML schema shows it is returning the username.

```
<z:row xmlns:z='#RowsetSchema' 
       ows_ContentTypeId='0x0100115773AE97ADF5418FF3A1AE2F660D3E' 
       ows_User='SHAREPOINT\system' 
       ows_Acknowedgement_x0020_Date='2013-01-01 00:00:00' 
       ows_ID='17' ows_ContentType='Item' 
       ows_Modified='2013-01-01 12:24:01' 
       ows_Created='2012-12-31 14:40:51' 
       ows_Author='1073741823;#System Account' 
       ows_Editor='1073741823;#System Account' />
```

Any idea what I did wrong in this?

Comment: If you perform a count on the listEnumeration will you get any results at all?

Comment: Yea, I do get count as 4 SPListItem objects since I have 4 items in the list.

Comment: Then, does the listEnumeration know that it is of type SPListItem? possibly add bool a = listEnumeration.Cast<SPListItem>().Any(...

Comment: @Trikks Tried that and Contains(), still returns false.

Comment: @Trikks, sorry, listEnumeration.Count() returns 0. I wonder why since I saw the count while debugging and it shows as 4 SPListItems. Doing it explicitly returns 0.

Comment: Then you should change the line var listEnumeration = l.Items.OfType<SPListItem>(); to var listEnumeration = l.Items.Cast<SPListItem>();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
SPList l = web.Lists["Acknowledgements"];
var listEnumeration = l.Items.Cast<SPListItem>();
bool a = listEnumeration.Any(p => p["User"].ToString().Equals(@"SHAREPOINT\system"));
```

Comment: `Cast` vs `OfType` is identical here, as everything in `l.Items` _is_ an `SPListItem`. Unless you've changed something else I haven't noticed, this shouldn't have made a blind bit of difference.

Comment: OfType - return only the elements of type SPListItem.
Cast - will try to cast all the elements into type SPListItem. Im unable to check at the moment but obviously the items in l.Items isn't of type SPListItem until we casted them.

Comment: Why isn't it working with `OfType`? I just retrieved the items from the list. It should've been `SPListItem`. Was there something wrong with the code? Tried running it with `OfType` but it didn't work.

Comment: I agree, it's very strange. OfType works in my environments but I recall having had issues with it before.

Comment: `l.items` is of type `SPListItemCollection` not `IEnumerable<SPListItem>` which is why `OfType` doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you really should not use list.Items.linq for finding target ListItems. Try to use SPQuery with target properties, it's much more faster and reliable.
http://www.aidangarnish.net/post/Using-SPQuery-and-CAML-to-filter-and-order.aspx

Comment: My technical lead asked me to use LINQ here cuz my other team members are using LINQ as well. Just to have consistency, I've been using LINQ as well.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. Went over many articles before posting this question and many recommended SPQuery. Wanted to just find a way to do this using LINQ. I'll surely try it using SPQuery. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`p["User"].ToString()` is probably not returning the account name verbatim, but a "lookup" value that, as a string, looks like `"1;#DOMAIN\logon"` or similar.

Canonically, you should be parsing `p["User"]` as an [`SPFieldUserValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfielduservalue.aspx), but you can probably get away with just using `Contains` rather than `Equals` in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Forgot to mention that "User" here is a column in the list i'm trying to query. Will try with Contains though.

Comment: Yup, I figured that out :p

Comment: Heh. So how do I do that? Pass it as SPFieldUserValue?

Comment: To be honest the quickest way to fix this would be to write all your `p["User"]` strings to the console and then work out why the strings don't match your expected string. At the moment I'm just stabbing in the dark for what your field type may be and what returning it as a string may give.

Comment: Tried Contains(), still returns false. I'mma try the Console method now. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for Contains() as well. Doesn't work with Equals(). Tried outputting that in Console but I get all types of exceptions when I try to lookup the website with a URL using WebApplication. I'm kinda new to SharePoint. Sorry for asking such a silly question.